# How to add .dll reference to ironpython VS2010 project?

Tags: ironpython, sharpsvn

I have a sharpsvn .net library i want to use in ironpython project. Library is shipped as a .ney .dll file. For C# projects i just add this file to project "Reference" section and after that i can use a library:

[alt text http://j.mp/8Y3MfL](http://j.mp/8Y3MfL)

But for IronPython, the "Reference" section opens very strange window i can't figure out how to add .dll reference to it. Is it any way to reference .net .dll library in IronPython other than GAC?

[alt text http://j.mp/az6XLW](http://j.mp/az6XLW)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add Reference dialog should not be used. Instead you can

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(...) ' with path
```

or configure SearchPath directory and use AddReference

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("SharpSvn")
```

Comment: First samle throws exception 'file not found'. File with path in exception exists. Second one throws IOError with "Could not add reference to assembly SharpSvn" :(

Comment: The error is that SharpSvn assembly is built against .net 2.0 and cannot be used by 4.0 runtime without additional configuration Issue itself and workarounds are described here - http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/26165.

Comment: Thanks alot. But with link provided it's only a question without an answer. The last message from topicstarter is "never mind, i have done it myself" :(. Maybe you have information about exact steps i need to perform in oder to use this .NET 2.0 .dll with IronPython?

Comment: you need to add or modify file ipy.exe.config with content <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>

Comment: If I added this lines I get WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v1.1.4322

** (/usr/lib/ironpython/ipy.exe:8994): WARNING **: Missing method System.Environment::SetEnvironmentVariable(string,string) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/1.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/ironpython/ipy.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable'.

Comment: @desco A contents of manifest must start with <configuration> tag.

Answer (score 2):

You add them in the script itself, something like this.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("SharpSvn.dll")
```

Comment: It throws exception 'file not found'. File with path in exception exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the IronPython solution and right-click on Search path and Add a new search path. Once this is done the folder your DLL is in will be in the search path like the screen shot

[Search Path http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aef2b4a74f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aef2b4a74f.png)

Once that is done you need to do

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("SharpSvn.dll")
```

Comment: A good example of why you should avoid using external links in SO. The png link above does not take you to an image.