# How to install an additional .NET library?

Tags: c#, .net, libraries, ironpython

I'm a beginner .NET programmer (C# and IronPython).

I've come across [WatiN](http://watin.org/) .NET library which will show handy for what I'm trying to do. The website claims that it is compatible with any .NET language, so I assume it's compatible with IronPython as well.

How do I go about installing it? Their website only has some instructions, using NUget in Visual Studio. I neither use Visual Studio nor am I interested in it. How and where would I put the downloaded files in order to make it work with IronPython?

Comment: NuGet is accessible from the command line, not just from Visual Studio.  http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library is a .dll file ( or many ), if you used nuget there should be a folder called packages in your solution folder and in there a folder with your dll.

What you want is to add a reference to that dll. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414705/how-to-add-dll-reference-to-ironpython-vs2010-project)

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, I did *NOT* use NUget as I do *NOT* use Visual Studio.

Comment: @Deusdies, sorry late hour :) its the same thing though. put the dll in your solution and check the answer in the link I gave you.

Comment: Thanks. I finally solved the problem by putting the .dll file in the directory where the interpreter was. For some reason it's not obeying the PATH.